# How can I define a default namespace for my XSLT XPaths? (XSLT 2.0)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML that I'd like to transform with XSL to view in a browser.

I have made the default namespace in my XML `http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0`. To avoid using prefixes in the XML and XSL, I added `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"` to my `xsl:stylesheet` element. I still seem to need prefixes in my xpaths, however, since xpaths with no prefixes do not work.

What am I missing? Shouldn't the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute ensure that I can use the default namespace in my xpaths, thus avoiding the need to prefix the (default) namespace?

I am hosting the XML and XSL on my own web server (Debian Bullseye, Apache, Raspberry Pi). Could there be an issue with the packages I have installed? For example, I have `libxslt1.1` installed, which only "supports" XSLT 1.0 (which doesn't include the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute). But shouldn't the XML be transformed by the browser, and not by my server?

**The XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mezzo.xsl" version="2.0"?>

<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <teiHeader>
                <fileDesc>
                        <titleStmt>Canto 1 of Inferno</titleStmt>
                </fileDesc>
        </teiHeader>
        <text>
        ...
        </text>
</TEI>
```

**The XSL**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
                <body>
                        <h1>mezzo</h1>
                        <p>
                                <strong>Title Statement: </strong>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//titleStmt"/>
                        </p>
                </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Browsers use also only an XSLT 1.0 processor, mostly libxslt these days (e.g. Chrome, Safari, Edge), Mozilla has its only XSLT 1.0 engine but as other browsers has never made an attempt to update their XML or XSLT stack. If you want to use XSLT 2 (well, 3, really) in the browser you can do so using Saxonica's Saxon-JS 2, see https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml and https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT defines a "forwards compatibility mode", which means that if you submit a stylesheet specifying version="2.0" to an XSLT processor that only supports 1.0, the processor ignores elements and attributes that it doesn't understand, in this case `xpath-default-namespace`.

(Whether this was a good design decision remains an open question. In this particular case the new attribute completely changes the meaning of the code, so an error message would have been better. But the 1.0 processor doesn't know that, of course.)

Comment: It depends on which XSLT 1.0 processor you are using. Both libxslt and Xalan will execute the stylesheet, ignoring the attribute - but they will also issue an error message. Saxon 6.5 and MS will proceed without warning.

Comment: To be more precise, libxslt warns about the version, while Xalan warns specifically about the "xpath-default-namespace" attribute.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the spec, not about specific products. Forwards compatibility mode is not always implemented exactly as defined in the spec (and of course some 1.0 products have been updated since 2.0 was published, which makes it easier to do something sensible -- some have even cherry-picked bits of the 2.0 spec.)